# Heroku error - getting deprecation error, app stopped working.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gemfile

I pushed my latest code and then my heroku app stopped working. I checked the logs and got an error message. Are there specific gems I should remove? Is this a db error?

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-05-23T00:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-05-23T00:08:11+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class UsersController (TypeError)
```

I ran a heroku run rake db:migrate in case that was the issue and got a similar warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
/app/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class UsersController (TypeError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-oauth'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'canard'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem 'formtastic'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'



group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'nifty-generators'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Are there specific gems I should remove?

Comment: post line 5 of app/config/environment.rb

Comment: This is line 5 of the environment.rb: App_name::Application.initialize!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here: a Deprecation WARNING and an error.  The error is

```
/app/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class UsersController (TypeError)
```

`superclass mismatch for class UsersController` What this usually means is that you're using a name thats already been used.  My first guess would be that you have a UsersController in you admin folder and in your root controllers folder, but thats just a guess.  Either way you're getting an error somewhere with calling the super class.

The deprectation warning should not cause any problems, just a warning to change that code for future versions of Rails.

Comment: Had the same issue. I had two `users_controller`s either under the controller root folder and an `admin` one.